# p value correction in multiple outcomes study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I am performing an analysis on different values of complement (in total 18, 9 in blood and 9 in CSF). We aim to analyze if any of these complement values:

1. Differentiate between 3 diseases (Disease 1, Disease 2 and Disease 3)
2. Predict 3 different outcomes (EDSS at last follow up (numerical, with a quantile regression), time to EDSS > 3 (with a cox regression) and number of relapses (with a Poisson regression).

However we have also explored more outcomes (4 more, time to EDSS > 6, presence/absence of relapses, EDSS == 6, EDSS == 3). We also explored these outcomes in subsets of patients. We firstly explored the univariate analysis, using the values of complement as predictors and then we adjusted each analysis by age, follow up time and sex.

When performing the p value correction, I don't know which approach could be more convenient:

A) Performing the p value correction for the global number of comparisons: 19 x 7.

B) Adjusting for 19 x 4 outcomes (the ones that we will publish).

C) Adjusting in each analysis by 19 outcomes.

Comment: Are the different test results likely to be correlated?  Would you consider a dimension reduction step (eg PCA)? Also your objectives (discrimination and prediction) may not be best addressed by p-values for each comparison, since a significant association does not tell you whether a marker is a good predictor of outcomes or good discriminator between groups.

Comment: Some of the blood tests results are correlated. I know the p values are not my main outcome, I am expressing everything in terms of OR or beta, but I would need a step of p-value correction. Regarding PCA, I already performed it, but we want to investigate which individual factor predicts better the outcome

Comment: In this question there are blood tests and statistical tests. It's not quite clear what analyses have been done, or even what the "outcomes" are. For example, I am at a loss where the 4 in the 19 x 4 outcomes to be published comes from. I'd guess you'll get more relevant answers if you clarify the details.

Comment: I edited the question, making it clearer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Standing on PWCs

You may find that there are alternative views on pairwise tests, particularly with cases like yours where there are a substantial number of mean comparisons being made. Some dictate that doing so comes at a severe loss of power and thus are not recommended (Nakagawa, 2004), some view that correction is necessary to preventing catastrophically poor decisions in hypothesis testing (Bennett et al., 2009), and others have a by-context view on the matter (Midway et al., 2020).

Personally, the more I learn about p-value correction, the more I feel it becomes troublesome with several comparisons. First, it speaks nothing at all to the actual mean differences between groups. Second, it only gives you a decision framework to act upon the precision of the estimate rather than the estimate itself. Third, it isn't really addressing the major theoretical interest you are pursuing, which is likely lost in a maze of comparisons that on their own aren't meaningful but aggregated probably mean something more. Fourth, as noted above, the tests themselves become severely underpowered when many tests are conducted, accomplishing the opposite approach that they are designed for (correcting alpha errors).

##### Alternatives

If it was up to me, I think a better option would be to run a linear mixed effects model (Brown, 2021), using the grouping factor here (blood test type), coding the groups as a random intercept, and then seeing what the overall difference in means is based on conditional shifts from this intercept. Running a billion PWCs probably isn't going to get you much unless you group these tests into reduced, meaningful categories. Otherwise I fail to see what an inferential test between 19 different groupings would help inform people related to your question of interest.

Another approach, as noted by others and is another from of data reduction, is simply running some kind of PCA on your features if they are highly correlated. But that is assuming they can be reduced in such a way.

##### Edit

If you are just interested in differences across *all* tests but are less concerned with a theoretical effect of interest, you could simply construct a mixed model where only tests are entered as random effects, and if there are no other effects of interest, they can be simply compared in this way. A commonly used example is shown below from the `sleepstudy` data in R, where here I only enter by-subject differences in reaction time into the model:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lmerTest)

#### Fit Model ####
fit.lmer <- lmer(Reaction ~ (1|Subject),
            data = sleepstudy)
summary(fit.lmer)
```

We can see from the fixed effects in the summary that the conditional mean reaction time is around 300 ms and this can vary considerably by subject (SD is around 35.75):

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 1278     35.75   
 Residual             1959     44.26   
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   298.51       9.05  17.00   32.98   <2e-16 ***
```

We can inspect the differences across several groups easily, or in this case subjects, by running the random effects like below:

```
#### Inspect Differences ####
ranef(fit.lmer)
```

We see for example that Subject 308 has a conditional mean reaction time that is about 38 ms larger than the average response (aka slow to respond), whereas Subject 309 is a quick responder and thus has an average reaction time that is about 72 ms less than average. Note that there are about 18 subjects here, so this example somewhat resembles the number of levels for your use case:

```
$Subject
    (Intercept)
308   37.829172
309  -72.209816
310  -58.536727
330    4.087222
331    9.476087
332    7.625658
333   15.305131
334   -2.779868
335  -42.001706
337   66.953479
349  -19.660707
350   13.089079
351   -7.292650
352   33.743025
369    6.526637
370   -5.901763
371   -3.055622
372   16.803368
```

Doing this, we can easily aggregate the overall variance in effects across many clusters (in your case the blood test types) as well as specific cluster differences by random intercepts.

**Note:** This is all assuming a single dependent variable case. As Dipetkov rightfully states, your distinction about a 19 x 4 outcome is unclear and may require some additional detail for a better answer. I assumed that you meant some type of medical outcome for multiple diseases (aka acquiring a diabetes-related disability).

##### Citations

- Bennett, C. M., Baird, A. A., Miller, M. B., & Wolford, G. L. (2009). Neural correlates of interspecies perspective taking in the post-mortem Atlantic salmon: An argument for proper multiple comparisons correction. Journal of Serendipitous and Unexpected Results, 1(1), 1–5.
- Brown, V. A. (2021). An introduction to linear mixed-effects modeling in R. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 4(1), 1–19. https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920960351
- Midway, S., Robertson, M., Flinn, S., & Kaller, M. (2020). Comparing multiple comparisons: Practical guidance for choosing the best multiple comparisons test. PeerJ, 8, e10387. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.10387
- Nakagawa, S. (2004). A farewell to Bonferroni: The problems of low statistical power and publication bias. Behavioral Ecology, 15(6), 1044–1045. https://doi.org/10.1093/beheco/arh107

Comment: Thank you for the complete revision of the topic. I do not know if I understood the linear mixed models approach. You would use the blood test as fixed effect factor, but I did not understand what would you employ as random effect. What would it be the predicted value in this case?

Comment: I've provided an example in my edit.

Comment: I've added more clarifications in the question

Comment: Now that I've read more about what you have done so far, it seems that I agree with Michael that doing anything confirmatory at this point would likely not be valid...this is essentially hypothesizing after results are known (HARKing) and it is considered bad practice for null hypothesis testing. I would abandon anything resembling a p-value at this point and simply report an exploratory study showing the trends you have observed from your data.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering regarding your approach that all the measures should be in the same scale, and it should be center and scaled

Comment: If you mean a mixed model approach which only uses the blood test factor as a random intercept, then there is no need to center or scale the data at all. You usually only do this if you are trying to adjust for either 1) uninterpretable intercepts or 2) multiple predictors in a regression, wherein you want to adjust for the average effect of other predictors. These aren't an issue in your case. However, I think Michael's approach is probably the best one here. Exploring the data and possibly setting up a follow up design that confirms your findings.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are performing a preliminary or characterisation study. In that situation you should not 'correct' for multiple comparisons at all. You should see what the data say and then design a second study (i.e. new data and possibly a new design) to test any hypotheses that you come up with.

Even if you are planning to publish the study results you should not apply a correction that will lead to a discount being applied to the evidence that you turn up. False negative errors are just as important as false positives in many types of characterisations. A potentially useful blood test that might be lost due to the power-sapping effects of multiple comparisons 'corrections' is potentially much more valuable than the cost of someone setting up an experiment to test a false hypothesis.

Many of the problems with 'corrections' for multiplicity are mentioned in Shawn Hemelstrand's excellent answer, but I will add another: correction for multiplicity entails all of the costs that Shawn mentions without any countervailing benefit in many circumstances. The 'corrections' correct for accumulation of global false positive errors even when the study is not intended to result in all or none decisions that might be counted as false positive errors. For a hypothesis generating or preliminary study the findings of interest are documented rather than tested and so no false positive error can  occur. The worst that can happen is that the hypothesis is found wanting in a subsequent study.

You cannot test a hypothesis with the data that led you to for the hypothesis because the data will always be biassed in favour of the hypothesis if that hypothesis is false. Otherwise the (false) hypothesis would not have been suggested by the data! Multiple comparisons 'corrections' control for that problem only by penalising all hypotheses, be they false or true.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The problem is that submitting a similar paper into a medical journal I argued that p correction value was arbitrary, and they finally forced me to do p-value correction because they said FDR correction such as Benjamini-Hochberg solved this matter.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Shawn and Michael that your current analysis may not need to prioritize p-value correction but define your research questions (i.e. hypotheses) well. It is still controversial how p values should be corrected, especially with multiple correlated hypotheses are involved. From your description, it appears that you have 6 response-variable measures that you call health outcomes, 19 blood assays that you suspect can predict the outcomes, and 3 diseases that may affect the 19 blood assay results. Here you have two layers of effect links: 3 diseases → 19 blood assays → 6 health outcomes, although your data were not generated from a randomized experimental design.

To connect the links, you want to learn about mediation effects and use structural equation modeling. Your case can use R package {systemfit} to estimate multiple equation simultaneously and give both direct effects (through other mechanisms) and indirect effects (through blood conditions) of diseases on health outcomes. You should examine interaction effects among three diseases, among 19 blood assays, and between three diseases and 19 blood assays, when they are used as predictors. However, this modeling technique is limited to linear models. In case the blood assays and health outcomes are not measured continuously over the entire real axis, you may have a limited-response problem if the dependent variable is binary, ordinal, count, positive, censored, etc. You could use the control-function approach in the instrument-variable paradigm when having endogenous predictors in generalized linear models, but it is a highly advanced method that I do not think your reviewers will truly appreciate.

P-value correction is usually useful in the descriptive data analysis part to give preliminary simple relationships with multiple groups but not in your case. In your descriptive analysis, you can make plots comparing mean (or median) values of blood assays and health outcomes (25 variables) by disease status which I assume are three binary variables of six categories. For each response variable, you can use a Wilcox test to compare the distribution by each binary disease indicator. Since each disease has only two categories, no p-value adjustment is needed. You can also make correlation plots between blood assays and health outcomes, showing 19 by 6 association statistics. You can but you don't have to to adjust these 114 p values here, as X uncorrelated to Y does not indicate that X, when Z is accounted for, is also uncorrelated to Y. So, you do not want to reduce a multiple-variate analysis (structural equations) to a univariate analysis (correlation coefficients).