multiple t test analysis or indidivual t tests
I have to analyse samples with t tests. I am not sure if I should treat my samples as individual t tests or multiple t tests. here the details:
I have an experiment where I analysed the concentration of 30 different metabolites for time 24 and 48 hours. So I am interested in knowing if there are significant differences between time 24 and 48 hours for each metabolite. I am not interested in knowing if the metabolites are different from each other. I was thinking in running 30 individual t tests (one t test for each metabolite evaluating 24 and 48 hours) but I am not sure if that is ok, or if I should run multiple t tests considering all the 30 metabolites. In case multiple is needed could someone let me know the reason of it.
thanks

The answer will depend on things that you might not have thought about. FOr example, do you want to evaluate the evidence concerning each of the metabilites, or do you want to make a decision regarding them? Is this a preliminary experiment whose outcomes will lead to the design of further experiments? See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324 and here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628319/p-value-correction-in-multiple-outcomes-study/628345#628345

hi thanks... there will not be further experiments due these results came from preliminary experiments that were used as a reference to run this experiment with the 30 metabolites evaluated at different times. I know that when analysing "n " t tests is necessary to adjust p values with the FDR or Holm-Sidak. However as my metabolites are analysed separately from each other , then I am not sure if I need to adjust or not for p -value

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You probably measure this with several units and for each unit you can couple for each of the 30 metabolites a 24 hours and 48 hours measurement? In such case you might have a use of combining the analyses of the 30 metabolites in a single model. Namely, the variances for the metabolites might differ in the same way from unit to unit.

hi my experiment is an in vitro fermentation involving faecal sample with a plant powder rich in  different metabolites. I evaluated the in vitro metabolism of these metabolites for 24 hours and 48 hours to see their concentrations in those period of time. it is just one volunteer then it is not a two way anova.

@Ricardor You have just one single volunteer (your data is 60 numbers? For 2 time points and 30 metabolites), then how did you think about using a t-test or other analysis? Or do you have multiple measurements from a single or multiple faecal sample?

I had in reality 3 volunteers. however for this type of experiments, the results from the 3 volunteers are averaged. I have 30 measurements for time 24 and 30 measurements for time 48. I am interested in analysing differences between times not among all the metabolites

You probably measure this with several units and for each unit you can couple for each of the 30 metabolites a 24 hours and 48 hours measurement?
In such case you might have a use of combining the analyses of the 30 metabolites in a single model. Namely, the variances for the metabolites might differ in the same way from unit to unit. A mixed effects model can deal with this. (there is a question related this somewhere, but I cannot find it)
Alternatively you can also turn around the analysis and predict the time as function of the metabolites. This has the advantage that potential complex interactions between the metabolites and variations between units for these interactions can be recovered. See also: Regression in sex differences multiple dependent variables

Since you do not care about comparing the metabolites which each other, you should run 30 t-tests (use Welch t-tests -unequal variances; out of the 30 comparisons you are bound to have several where the variances are different). So your initial thought is the right one.
Now, you are now faced with the "multiple comparison" problem. Corner of the envelope calculation: out of 30 comparisons, at the "traditional" $\alpha=0.05$ significance level, you would expect $1.5$ false positive result (assuming the null -no difference between 24 and 48 hours- is true for all of them). Using the binomial distribution probabilities, your chance of getting 0 false positive result is only $21 \%$. So you will get 1 (or more) $79 \%$ of the time... Not great odds.
Now, the textbook answer is "you should use a multiple comparison correction (MCC)". Bonferroni, Sidak, etc. But, as the links graciously provided by @Michael Lew show, that textbook answer is a bit simplistic, and more nuanced answers can be given. Yes, a MCC will control your type 1 error rate at 5% (instead of 21%), but at a significant loss of power in your test (i.e. at a significant risk of significant increase of false negatives - type 2 errors).
So to paraphrase Dirty Harry, the question becomes "Do you feel lucky?". How bad would a false positive be? How bad would a false negative be? Will there be confirmatory experiment(s)? Etc. It depends on what you (or your audience/sponsor) will do with the result; what would be the recommendation, what would be the decision? It is not clear from your question.
You may decide to not use a MCC, based on the specific use of the results in your context. But you should address the MCC issue (instead of acting as if it does not even exist).

hi thanks a lot for your answer. my experiment is an in vitro fermentation involving faecal sample with a plant powder rich in different metabolites. I evaluated the in vitro metabolism of these metabolites for 24 hours and 48 hours. this is a final experiment performed after some previous experiments. now we wanted to understand how bacteria from faecal sample metabolized these metabolites from the plant powder.  As you mentioned that it depends what I will do with these data, then I imagine I should go for multiple comparison correction?
