Choosing p-adjustment method in pairwise Wilcox test
I need some help in choosing p-adjustment method in my pairwise wilcox test on weights in four different independent groups (using R).
I have been reading about the different methods and googled numerous answers. I am a statistics novice so unfortunately many of them become too complicated, but my conclusion is that the method depends on the data. So I was wondering if someone could give me some tips or guidelines depending on my data (see test result below).
I have tested all available methods ("bonferroni", "holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "BH", "BY"), and they basically give similar significance result except the Benjamini & Yekutieli method.
If anyone know of general guidelines in choosing method depending on the data, please let me know (I have failed to find any).
The result of my test is as follows:
BH method (as an example - the p.adj value for N-A is the same for all except BY):
 .y.        group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic   p   p.adj p.adj.signif
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>       
1 Weight      S      N       127  7696  478037  0.673 0.673 ns          
2 Weight      S      A       127   164   11542  0.113 0.226 ns          
3 Weight      S      T       127   195   11720  0.417 0.625 ns          
4 Weight      N      A      7696   164  711349  0.005 0.031 *           
5 Weight      N      T      7696   195  734472  0.613 0.673 ns          
6 Weight      A      T       164   195   14233  0.073 0.219 ns          

BY method:
   .y.       group1 group2  n1    n2    statistic     p   p.adj   p.adj.si
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <chr>       
1 Weight       S      N     127  7696      478037   0.673  1        ns          
2 Weight       S      A     127   164       11542   0.113  0.554    ns          
3 Weight       S      T     127   195       11720   0.417  1        ns          
4 Weight       N      A    7696   164      711349   0.005  0.077    ns          
5 Weight       N      T    7696   195      734472   0.613  1        ns          
6 Weight       A      T     164   195       14233   0.073  0.536    ns  

Note that there are considerably more samples for group N that the others.
Two questions:

Which method should I use?
Why is BY different?


Why do you think you need to adjust for multiple comparisons? What is the context of your experiment and what types of inferences are you thinking of making? See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324 and here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628319/p-value-correction-in-multiple-outcomes-study/628345#628345

The reason I am looking for adjustment is solely that this is recommended in most sites that discusses the method. I am simply comparing weights of individuals in several unrelated groups and want to see if they differ significantly. Thank you for the links. I tested using "none" as adjustment and got similar results although all the p.adj was lower.

If you adjusted p-values were lower than the unadjusted then I have to guess that something is wrong. Critical values for dichotomising into significant and not significant get lower, but the adjusted p-values should get higher.

The methods don't depend on the data, but on what risks you are willing to take between making false "discoveries" and missing true "discoveries."
The first choice you have to make is whether you want to control for the family-wise error rate (FWER) or the false discovery rate (FDR). The FWER is the probability of making any false discoveries among your comparisons. The FDR is the fraction of your "discoveries" that's expected to be false.
Control of FDR is usually done in situations like evaluating the expression levels of thousands of genes, in which you are willing to accept some false positives so that you don't miss potentially important discoveries. For your type of study, evaluating paired comparisons after a set of Wilcoxon tests, you want to control the FWER.
All the tests you tried effectively evaluate the sequence of p-values in ascending order. You can think about them as adjusting the p-values, based on the total number of p-values and the order of a p-value in that sequence.
In all except the Benjamini–Yekutieli (BY) method for controlling FDR, the lowest p-value is multiplied by the total number of p-values. The BY method multiplies it by even more, the inverse of the harmonic number of the number of p-values, to allow for negative correlations among the p-values. That's why it differs from the others.
FWER control means using one of the Bonferroni, Holm, Hochberg, or Hommel methods. The Bonferroni is the easiest to explain: if you are doing 6 comparisons, multiply all the p-values by 6 and only accept those that meet your FWER significance criterion (evidently 0.05 here).
That ends up being much too stringent, however, once you get beyond the lowest p-value in the list. The Holm (or "Holm-Bonferroni") method provides a less-stringent control on the subsequent p-values, and is a good general choice that is always more powerful (rejecting fewer true "discoveries") than the Bonferroni method. The Hochberg and Hommel methods can be even more powerful but they require assumptions about independence or positive dependence among the p-values. The Wikipedia page on the Holm-Bonferroni method explains in detail.
An alternative to doing multiple pairwise Wilcoxon tests would be to perform an ordinal logistic regression on your data. That can be considered a generalization of the Wilcoxon test that allows for more complicated experimental designs and for post-modeling analysis applicable to regression models, like those provided by the emmeans package or the rms package in R.

Thank you for the very comprehensive answer! I think I know how to proceed now. I will test you suggestions.

You may have chosen the hard way of doing things? It seems you are performing multiple Wilcoxon Rank Sum tests (aka Mann-Whitney U tests -MWUt-; aka test of stochastic superiority). And that you need to find p-value adjustments.
But there is an omnibus test for comparing multiple samples for stochastic superiority, the Kruskal-Wallis test (KWt) (it is, to the MWUt, what the ANOVA is to the Student t-test). If its p-value is significant, it will mean that at least one sample is stochastically superiot to at least another one. And then there is multiple comparison correction (MCC) just for the KWt (just like there are for ANOVA, such as Tukey, Dunnett, etc.), specifically the Dunn test (see here for its R implementation).
There is nothing theoretically wrong with performing all the pairwise comparisons, but you would not do that if you were interested in the means; you woudl run an ANOVA. So... I know I would at a minimum give this a try.

Thank you for your suggestions! I have tested the KWt test, but I failed to find a related MCC test. I have also run an ANOVA. I wanted to test several methods an see if there are differences between them. For instance, if the ANOVA discovers differences the  Wilkinson does not (and vice versa), I would have to look closer to determine the reason. One of the reasons I do several tests is that one of my groups have a very larger sample that the rest and this has caused some inconsistency in the results.

The question about choosing p-adjustment method still remains with the Dunn-method, though. Tested the Dunn method and the results are very similar to the Wilcoxon test.

The Dunn post-hoc test is a p-adjustment method; it answers the question... ANOVA and KWt have completely different null hypotheses; so it is not at all surprising that they give different results on the same data. The fact that the sample sizes are unbalanced is not an issue for ANOVA, or KWT, etc., as long as you meet the respective assumptions for the test.
