Multiple Testing p-value Adjustment and Preservation of Significant Differences
When adjusting for multiple hypothesis tests, a non-uniform distribution of p-values that has a promising-looking Q-Q plot ends up with all adjusted p-values far above 0.05. Are there other multiple testing adjustments which retain signficance for all points which diverge from the diagonal line? A minimal R-coded example is:
pValues <- seq(0.05, 1, length.out = 1000)
pValues <- c(0.00005 + c(0.001 * 2^(seq(0, 5, 0.5))), pValues)
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "BH"))
  0.69 0.69 0.69 0.73 0.82 0.96
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "holm"))
  1 1 1 1 1 1
> head(p.adjust(pValues, "fdr"))
  0.69 0.69 0.69 0.73 0.82 0.96

The corresponding Q-Q plot looks like:
library(qqplotr)
plotData <- data.frame(pValues)
ggplot(plotData, mapping = aes(sample = pValues)) + 
    stat_qq_line(distribution = "unif") +
    stat_qq_band(distribution = "unif") + 
    stat_qq_point(distribution = "unif")



It's not clear what you mean by "a promising-looking QQ plot" in context of P-values; these are uniform under the null so your plot looks almost exactly like what you'd get in that case. The fact that a handful of them might be a little smaller than expected is not something you'd readily pick up under a multiplicity correction of this size, and FDR control is about as liberal as those come.

There are many circumstances where 'correction' for multiple comparisons can be applied, but really should not be. They trade off power to detect interesting effects for protection of false positive error rates, and the error rates are often not the most important thing for inference.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628319/p-value-correction-in-multiple-outcomes-study/628345#628345 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630316/how-many-p-value-observations-do-you-think-are-required-before-doing-fdr-correct/630324#630324
